# cannot create temp file for here-document: no space left on device when I use tab

Tags: ubuntu, tabs, temp

when I use tap for cd,
this error come.

cannot create temp file for here-document: No spae left on device

and below is the df -i results.

there are many /dev/loop folders,
what is it? and what should I do?

```
beomgon@beomgon-p4000:/$ df -i
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            4062709    608  4062101    1% /dev
tmpfs           4072883   1161  4071722    1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p4   918464 231237   687227   26% /
tmpfs           4072883      1  4072882    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           4072883      5  4072878    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           4072883     18  4072865    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1        39455  39455        0  100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1313
/dev/loop3          747    747        0  100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
/dev/loop4         1550   1550        0  100% /snap/gnome-calculator/406
/dev/loop0        12823  12823        0  100% /snap/core/7396
/dev/loop5         1720   1720        0  100% /snap/gnome-logs/45
/dev/loop9          734    734        0  100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/100
/dev/loop6        27707  27707        0  100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/67
/dev/loop10         354    354        0  100% /snap/gnome-logs/61
/dev/nvme0n1p1   124928    304   124624    1% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p3        0      0        0     - /boot/efi
/dev/loop13       10041  10041        0  100% /snap/core18/1074
/dev/loop12         271    271        0  100% /snap/gnome-characters/296
/dev/loop14       27345  27345        0  100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
/dev/loop15         271    271        0  100% /snap/gnome-characters/317
/dev/loop16       27707  27707        0  100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/71
/dev/loop17       27631  27631        0  100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/90
/dev/sda1      61054976 626656 60428320    2% /home
tmpfs           4072883     23  4072860    1% /run/user/121
tmpfs           4072883     37  4072846    1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop18       10041  10041        0  100% /snap/core18/1098
/dev/loop2        27631  27631        0  100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/92
/dev/loop8         1574   1574        0  100% /snap/gnome-calculator/501
/dev/loop7        12827  12827        0  100% /snap/core/7713
```